# Autostart with umlauts in american keyboad

Tags: keyboard, autostart

I ve an american keyboard on my notebook but I need german umlauts.
I configured that in the xmodmap ( which is in home directory )  and with

```
xmadmap .Xmodmap
```

in terminal I can write with the umlauts.
I don t want to enter the  comands every time in the terminal when using the notebook, so I need a script that would do it.
I  am quite new in the linux world so I need some help.

Comment: also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2466191

Answer (score 2):

- To easily type international characters on a US american Querty keyboard, switch to the keyboard layout English US International with dead keys or English International with AltGr dead keys. These keyboard layouts allow for easy entry of international characters using a "dead key". Change/add or remove keyboard layout in "Settings" - "Keyboard", Input sources.
- If you are specifically looking for autostarting the `xmodmap` command, then put that program in your Startup Applications. In standard Ubuntu, search for "Startup Applications" to open the "Startup Application Preferences" dialog where you can add a startup program. To execute `xmodmap` systemwide, i.e. for all users and during log in, add the command in a script file in `/etc/profile.d`

Comment: Best solution: adding   xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap  to etc/profile. then you get the umlaut when starting the computer

Comment: Added this option to the answer, thank you.